# Mysql Hierarchy Find Parent id

Tags: mysql

I have got this mysql table. Mysql table is unlimited. I want to find id. But I can only use the seo column.

i want to find "sale" categories id. But This values is not unique.

Mysql Table:

```
  id   title      parent  seo
|  1  | Car      |  0   | car
|  2  | Estate   |  0   | estate
|  3  | Sale     |  1   | sale
|  4  | Rent     |  1   | rent
|  5  | Audi     |  3   | audi
|  6  | Bmw      |  4   | bmw
|  7  | Sale     |  2   | sale
|  8  | Rent     |  2   | rent
|  9  | Apartment|  7   | apartment
|  10 | Villa    |  8   | villa
...
```

For example: Select id From mytable WHERE seo="sale" but seo column is not unique.

I know url Hierarchy structure.

```
as:
.../ads/car/sale
.../ads/car/sale/bmw
```

i want this ouput:

```
myurl:  .../ads/car/sale
output id: 3

myurl:  .../ads/estate/sale
output id: 7

myurl:  .../ads/estate/sale/apartment
output id: 9
```

Comment: Can you at least show us the expected output?  I don't follow your question as it stands now.

Comment: I want to find id url. Examle: url: .../ads/car/sale/bmw I want to get "bmw" values id. But "sale" value isn't unique so i don't find id.

Comment: how you find this url pattern ../ads/car/sale/bmw ?

Comment: i can find it with php. Forexample: $link = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$link_array = explode('/',$link);

Comment: It comes category. http://example.com/ads/car/bmw then i get "$link = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; $link_array = explode('/',$link);".
$link_array[1]="car"; $link_array[2]="sale"; $link_array[3]="bmw"; i want to get last path id.